# Proper response for a boolean query (if resource exists)?

Tags: .net, rest, http-status-codes

I have a rest service endpoint that checks to see if a username is available or not. Currently I have it returning a boolean in either xml or json, but it feels awkward to me. I thought about it returning `200 OK` if the username is available and `409 Conflict` or `423 Locked` if it's not, but something about that felt awkward too.

So my question is, is there a proper/standard response for a service response such as this and what is it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with returning your value in an xml/json result.  This is pretty standard, even for something as simple as you are describing.  In fact, I would argue that using HTTP responses to determine a Boolean value would be much more awkward of an approach -- both from development *and* maintenance by future developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were developing this RESTful service, I would have returned an HTTP status code 404 [NOT_FOUND] with a body having something (like boolean) value signifying that a `username` was not found.

**Reason:**
REST is basically a terminology tightly coupled to resources. In this case, `username` is a resource. You are using a service to query and check the "state of the resource" (aka: whether a username is already present). Since REST works on top of HTTP, it is convenient to send a HttpStatus code pertaining to the state check you did for the resource.

You can think of it like "Getting a letter addressed to you from an organization with a subject as *Cannot find what you have requested for* and a letter body saying *Dear Sinaesthetic, we searched for what you were looking for but we are sorry we did not find one*".

I hope I am making sense here. :)

Comment: I decided to take the route where instead of checking if the the username is available, I check to see if they already exist. I return 200 if they do, 404 if they do not. Thanks!

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Exactly, that is the RESTful way to go. Glad I was of help. :)